# Prove that every set of $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with diameter $L$ can be covered by a cube with side length $L$.

Tags: geometry

Prove that every set of $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with diameter $L$ can be covered by a cube with side length $L$. 
Can someone show me the picture of draw it?
I can't figure it out in picture.

Comment: Please clarify in your question what you mean by a "a set of points with diameter $L$".

Answer (score 0):

I assume "n points with diameter L" means the max length between 2 points is L

**Hint:** Build a rectangle with $x, y, z$ the min values of each coordinate for the points of the set.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S\subset{\mathbb R}^n$ be an *arbitrary nonempty set*, and assume
$$L:=\sup\bigl\{|y-x|\>\bigm|\>x,\ y\in S\bigr\}<\infty\ .$$
Then $S$ is necessarily bounded. Define
$$a_i:=\inf\{x_i\>|\>x\in S\},\quad b_i:=\sup\{x_i\>|\>x\in S\}\qquad(1\leq i\leq n)\ .$$
I claim that $$b_i-a_i\leq L\qquad(1\leq i\leq n)\ .$$
*Proof.* Assume $b_1-a_1=L+2\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$. There is a point $x\in S$ with $x_1<a_1+\epsilon$ and a point $y\in S$ with $y_1>b_1-\epsilon$. It follows that
$$|y-x|\geq y_1-x_1>(b_1-\epsilon)-(a_1+\epsilon)=L\ ,$$
contradicting the definition of $L$.